# How to return parts of a string with regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I have multiple strings in the format:

```
"s mus_musculus.1          3003214       6673 +  195471971 ctctcctatggcggggaaggtgcctggatgtctaaagc-----------------ctgaa-atggggatctatcccagaagctgtgtagcttctgcctgtcccagaagctgtgttgtttct"
```

How can I use regular expressions to pull out the first number sequence (ie 3003214), and then the final sequence of "c, t, a, g, and -"?

I have tried various regular expression builders but have not been able to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unclear about the *final sequence 'c, t, a, g and -'*

Comment: Show the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code out:

```
text <- "s mus_musculus.1          3003214       6673 +  195471971 ctctcctatggcggggaaggtgcctggatgtctaaagc-----------------ctgaa-atggggatctatcccagaagctgtgtagcttctgcctgtcccagaagctgtgttgtttct"

number <- str_extract(text, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=\\s)")
string <- str_extract(text, "[\\w\\-]+(?=\\s*)$")

print(number)
print(string)
```

**[As demonstrated on rextester.com](http://rextester.com/XLX13229)**

## Explanation -

*For extracting the number:*

`(?<=\\s)` is a positive look-behind that tells the regex that whatever the number is, it should be preceded by a space. This is based purely on my assumption that the first number you want is followed and preceded by a space.
`\\d+` is the series of one-or-more digits you want to capture
`(?=\\s)` is a positive look-ahead that tells the regex that the number will be followed by a space.

*For extracting the string:*

`[\\w\\-]+` indicates one-or-more *word* characters or dashes (which becomes the captured string)
`$` asserts the position at the end of the string. So, whatever should be matched, must be at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
S <- "s mus_musculus.1          3003214       6673 +  195471971 ctctcctatggcggggaaggtgcctggatgtctaaagc-----------------ctgaa-atggggatctatcccagaagctgtgtagcttctgcctgtcccagaagctgtgttgtttct"

gsub(".*\\s(\\d+)\\s{2}.*\\s(\\D+)$", "\\1 \\2", S)
# "3003214 ctctcctatggcggggaaggtgcctggatgtctaaagc-----------------ctgaa-atggggatctatcccagaagctgtgtagcttctgcctgtcccagaagctgtgttgtttct"
```

- .* - match anything
- \\s - whitespace
- \\s{2} - 2 whitespaces
- (...) - capture group
- \\d+ - any number of contiguous numbers
- \\D+ - any number of contiguous characters
- $ - end of string
- \\1 - print capture group 1
- \\2 - print capture group 2